# Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer Logging in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

I am trying to create a Elastic Beanstalk in AWS, and need to enable access logs for the load balancer that the Beanstalk would create. I could not find any examples on the Terraform official documention where I could enable this feature via Terraform code

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "tftest" {
  name        = "tf-test-name"
  description = "tf-test-desc"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"
}
```

I am trying to enable access logs for the load balancer created by Beanstalk but there is no mention of such feature in Terraform documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use option settings for Elastic Beanstalk [1]:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "some_env" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
    name      = "AccessLogsS3Bucket"
    value     = "<valid S3 bucket name>"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
    name      = "AccessLogsS3Enabled"
    value     = "true"
  }

}
```

Using the same logic, you can optionally define the `AccessLogsS3Prefix` setting, but it is not required.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer

Comment: This did not work, Terraform gives an error -  failed Reason: Access denied for bucket: <bucket-name>. Please check S3bucket permissiob (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidconfigurationRequest

Comment: The answer is correct. However, it is on you to define the correct permissions on the bucket. The documentation says the following: `The Amazon S3 bucket where access logs are stored. The bucket must be in the same Region as the environment and allow the load balancer write access.`. So, you have to fix that.